# Qlik sense - Get selected id in custom exception

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am using qlik sense and i am writing a custom extension to display a chart. I want to know if there is way which all rows are selected in other extensions in my custom extension.

**Scenario:**

I am using two extensions in my sheet

1. **Filter pane(inbuild) - which filters a list of ids**
2. **Chart extension (Custom written) - displays a chart**

My scenario is, i use a REST Api call to get the data for my custom extension. When the filter is activated and some ids are filtered, i need to send these ids to back end to get the updated list for updating my custom chart.

Is there any way to do this ?? Please help i am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know the current selections of your filter pane object and then send these id's to your custom chart.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, here are a couple starting points:

- [Qlik Engine JSON API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2019/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/DiscoveringAndAnalysing/MakeSelections/get-current-selections.htm)
- [Capability API -> Selection API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2019/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/SelectionAPI/qlik-selectionState-interface.htm)
- [Capabilitiy API -> App API -> createList method](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2019/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/AppAPI/createList-method.htm)

I would use the last option and combine it with these resources: [Link 1](https://extendingqlik.upper88.com/get-the-selections-in-a-qlik-sense-mashup/) & [Link 2](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-Integration/How-to-get-ALL-selections-in-a-Field-in-a-Mashup/td-p/1367871)